# create new ul after every 13 li elements

Tags: php, html, opencart

First of all, I don't know how to count in php, maybe someone could recommend me a good source to read;

Second, I'm not asking to solve this for me, but I just want a hint or simpler explanation that would make sense;

Here is my function:

```
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><p><?php echo $category['name']; ?></p></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
        <ul>      
          <li class="none"><h1><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></h1></li>
        <?php if ($category['children'][$i]['children_level2']) { ?>     
        <?php for ($wi = 0; $wi < count($category['children'][$i]['children_level2']); $wi++) { ?>
           <li> 
          <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['name']; ?></a>
           </li>
         <?php } ?>
         <?php } ?>         
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

I want this part, every 13 li elements to create a new .ul. ./ul. tags

```
<?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
   <ul>      
      <li class="none"><h1><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></h1></li>
        <?php if ($category['children'][$i]['children_level2']) { ?>     
        <?php for ($wi = 0; $wi < count($category['children'][$i]['children_level2']); $wi++) { ?>
          <li> 
          <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['name']; ?></a>
       </li>
         <?php } ?>
         <?php } ?>         
    </ul>

  <ul><li>maximum of 13 elements</li></ul>
after 13 <li></li> elements create new <ul></ul> tags and put the 14 <li></li> element into the new <ul></ul> tag
```

I hope I explained what I want to do, for now I'll be waiting for your answers,

p.s. this is more for my learning skills then actual work, so thanks in advice

Comment: `I explained what I want to do, for now I'll be waiting for your answers` - it's not odesk.com, man. What have you tried?

Comment: Instead of opening and closing so many PHP tags, you should use the [print/echo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) functions to output content. It's hard to read your code like this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Use condition

```
if ($wi && $wi % 13 == 0) {
    print '</ul><ul>';
}
```

Comment: It works! this print function is such a simple way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

In order to count 13 elements, you can use the modulo operator `%`. The idea is that `($iw % 13)` is equal to 0 if the content of `$iw` is a multiple of 13. ([see more about the modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation))

With an `if` statement you can insert `</ul><ul>` when you need in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

There's two possibilities I can think of:

- you could have a separate counter wich resets to 1 and outputs a `<ul>` every time it reaches 13
- or you could check each time if `$wi` id divisible by 13:

  ```
   <?php
   for ($wi = 0; $wi < count($category['children'][$i]['children_level2']); $wi++) {
      if ($wi && $wi % 13 == 0) {
          // output <ul>
       }
   }
   ?>
  ```

If you're unsure what `%` means, here's the appropriate [PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)